# concatenating escape sequence string in macro

Tags: c++, macros

Say I want to use a macro that prepends `\x` to it's argument so that the replacement is a valid hex escape sequence, something like:

```
#define HEXIFY(s) "\x" s
...

std::cout << HEFIXY("48");
```

Or:

```
#define HEXIFY(s) "\x" #s
...

std::cout << HEXIFY(48);
```

Which would print the character `H` (hex 48).

Both of these snippets don't seem to work however. Is there a way I can accomplish this by only using macros?

Comment: I don’t think you can do that.

Comment: Have you tried compiling your source with the "-e" option? On many compilers, that option will preprocess your source and provide the preprocessed version so you can see what the preprocessor is doing. (Maybe not all compilers, but many).

Comment: I wonder what utility this macro has.  I would understand if `\x` was not the universally accepted escape sequence for hex constants, and you wanted to specify different flavors using a macro, but I don't see the purpose of this.  Also, it is more to type `HEXIFY(` than to type `\x`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're totally right, it has none. I wanted to use this specific macro in some personal golfing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define str(s) #s
#define XHEXIFY(x,y) (str(x##y))
#define HEXIFY(y) XHEXIFY(\x,y)

int main()
{
    cout<<HEXIFY(48)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```